# Cross-origin error using auth0 with angular

Tags: angular, typescript, auth0

I'm trying to get a management api access token from my auth0 api endpoint but I keep getting:

"header ‘access-control-allow-headers’ is not allowed according to header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Headers’ from CORS preflight response"

The following service has a function which is responsible for the request with the following code:

```
public getManagementAccessToken(){
    const httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, Access-Control-Allow-Origin',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS',
        })
    };

    const body = 'grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=${this.clientId}&client_secret=${this.clientSecret}&audience=${this.audience}';

    return this.http.post(this.apiUrl, body, httpOptions);
}
```

I've allowed the localhost with correct port and my domain address under allowed web origins and CORS. What am I doing wrong?